# How to find files in a directory that contain unique items from list or another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying write a Python3 script to parse a directory that contains files with bacterial species names and a protein sequence corresponding to each species. These files are called fasta files because the identifier (aka header) of each sequence start with a ">". Examples are below.

```
File_1
>Mycoplasma_hypo
MAKEIILGIDLGTTNSVVAIIENQKPVVLENPNGKTTTPSVVAFKNNEEIVGDAAKRQ
LETNPEAIASIKRLMGTDKTVRANNNNERDYKPEEISAKILAYLKEYAEKKIGHKVTK
>Mycoplasma_galli
MSNNNGLIIGIDLGTTNSCVSVMEGAQKVVIENPEGKRTTPSVVSYKNGEIIVGDAAKRQ
MLTNPNTIVSIKRLMGTSKKVKINDKGVEKELTPEEVSASILSYLKDYAEKKTGQKISR
>Mycoplasma_agal
MAKEVIIGIDLGTTNSVVSIVDNGSPVVLENLNGKRTTPSVVSFKDGEIIVGDNAKNQ
IETNPDTVASIKRLMGTSKTVHVNNNNNKDYKPEEISAMILEHLKKYAEEKIGHKIEK

File_2
>Mycoplasma_hypo
MAKEIILGIDLGTTNSVVAIIENQKPVVLENPNGKTTTPSVVAFKNNEEIVGDAAKRQ
LETNPEAIASIKRLMGTDKTVRANNNNERDYKPEEISAKILAYLKEYAEKKIGHKVTK
>Mycoplasma_galli
MSNNNGLIIGIDLGTTNSCVSVMEGAQKVVIENPEGKRTTPSVVSYKNGEIIVGDAAKRQ
MLTNPNTIVSIKRLMGTSKKVKINDKGVEKELTPEEVSASILSYLKDYAEKKTGQKISR
>Mycoplasma_galli
MSNNNGLIIGIDLGTTNSCVSVMEGAQKVVISVVSYKNLKDYAEKKHHGEIIVGDAAKRQ
MLTNPNTIVSIKRLMGTSKKVKI-NDKGVEKELTPEEVSASILSYLKDYAEKKTGQKISR
>Mycoplasma_gen
MAKENNVIIGIDLGTTNSVRTTPSVVSFKDGEIIVGDNAKNQVSIVDNGSPVVLENLNGK
IETNPDTVASIKRLMGTSKTVHVNNNNNNKDYKPEEISAMILEHLKKYAEEKIGHKIEK
```

As you can see **File_2** contains a duplicate (>Mycoplasma_galli). I would like to skip this file and create a directory of all other files the contain unique bacterial species from either a given list or another file that contains the names of these bacterial species. An example of such look up file can be:

LookUp_File

```
>Mycoplasma_galli 
>Mycoplasma_hypo
>Mycoplasma_gen
>Mycoplasma_agal
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
path = ["File_1.txt","File_2.txt"]

list_all = []
import re
for i in path:
    s=open(i).read()
    list_all = list_all + re.findall(r'(?<=\s)\>\w+',s) #Extracts all words start with '>'

list_uni = list(set(list_all))

f = open('lookup.txt', 'w+')

f.write("\n".join(list_uni))

f.close()
```